# ojdeploy - ant task compile application

Tags: ant, oracle-adf

I am trying to use ojdeploy to compile and build an ADF application through an AntTask.

The ojdeploy task works fine when I specify not to compile the project by adding the line

The ojdeploy task is unable to find several jars required to build the application which I have specified.

I can't find any documentation which describe the use of the ojdeploy to compile applications which makes me think that it does not work.

The ant task I have is below. My thoughts are that the ojdeploy task does not have the jars required to build the project on its classpath. I can't see a way to add these jars to the classpath however.

ojdeploy task:

```
 <target name="deploy" description="Deploy JDeveloper profiles">
    <property name="status" value="${env.WORKSPACE}/deploy/ojdeploy-statuslog.xml"/>
    <taskdef name="ojdeploy"
             classname="oracle.jdeveloper.deploy.ant.OJDeployAntTask"
             uri="oraclelib:OJDeployAntTask"
             classpathref="classpath"/>      
    <ora:ojdeploy xmlns:ora="oraclelib:OJDeployAntTask"
                  executable="${env.oracle.middleware}/jdeveloper/jdev/bin/ojdeploy.exe"
                  failonerror="true"
                  ora:buildscript="${env.WORKSPACE}/deploy/ojdeploy-build.xml"
                  ora:statuslog="C:/Oracle/Middleware/ojdeploy-statuslog.xml">
        <ora:deploy>
            <ora:parameter name="workspace"
                       value="${env.WORKSPACE}/JWS.jws"/>
            <ora:parameter name="profile"
                       value="*"/>
            <!--<ora:parameter name="nocompile" value="true"/>-->
            <ora:parameter name="outputfile"
                       value="${env.WORKSPACE}/deploy/${deployment.profile.name}"/>
      </ora:deploy>
    </ora:ojdeploy>
  </target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.

ojdeploy uses the jws and jpr files to find the libraries required. The jpr file was missing several JDeveloper/ADF libraries which JDeveloper is able to resolve.

However for ojdeploy to work ALL the libraries and dependencies are required to be in the jws/jpr file accordingly using the libraries/classpath and dependencies options.